# How to pass list array from Main class to A second class inside the same file?

Tags: c#, class, arraylist

So below I have two classes Program which is the main class and testing which is the second class. How can I pass the content of `List<String> list = new List<String>();` into the  `List<String> newList = new List<String>();` within the second class.

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          List<String> list = new List<String>();
          list.Add("Test1");

          testing client = new testing();

        } 
    }

    public class testing
    {
       List<String> newList = new List<String>();

    }
```

Comment: use constructor for that, create a constructor in testing class

Comment: @user7374935 you really should be doing some intro to C# tutorials/classes if you are still unsure what a constructor is.

Comment: posted below an example of how you would have to do this, but i think you need to study more first about how c# works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need here is create a constructor in `testing` class and pass in the object of `List<string>` from the calling code.

Construct your class like:

```
public class testing
{
   List<String> newList;

   public testing(List<string> input)
   {
       newList = input;
   }

}
```

Now you can call it via your Main method :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     List<String> list = new List<String>();
     list.Add("Test1");

     testing client = new testing(list);
}
```

Refer to the following post to understand the basics about Constructors:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/using-constructors

Answer (score 0):

Define a public property in test class and assign property from main class like below

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          List<String> list = new List<String>();
          list.Add("Test1");

          testing client = new testing();
          client.newList = list;

        } 
    }

    public class testing
    {
      public  List<String> newList { get; set;}


    }
```